# upload video using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, upload, retrofit

I want to upload a video file using Retrofit **2**, please help me doing this.

This is my endpoint:

**`upload.php`:**

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '../uploads/';
$uploadfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$response = array();
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$uploadfile)) 
{
    $response["result"] = "1";
    echo json_encode($response);
} else 
{
    $response["result"] = "-1";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

---

I tried to follow a sample (combining it with file selection from the gallery) on the web, but it doesn't even compile (I have marked the erroneous line by a comment):

**`MainActivity`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO = 1;
    String decodableString;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button btn_load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadVideo);
        btn_load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               loadVideoFromGallery(btn_load);
            }
        });
    }
    /*
     * PICK THE VIDEO AND EXTRACT ITS ADDRESS
     */
    public void loadVideoFromGallery(View view) 
    {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When a video is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) 
            {
                // Get the video from data
                Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                decodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Log.i("mok",decodableString);
                cursor.close();
                upload(decodableString);
            } else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked any video",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    /*
     * UPLOAD THE SELECTED VIDEO TO THE SRVER
     */

    public void upload(String decodableString)
    {
        final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.7/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

        UploadApiService service = retrofit.create(UploadApiService.class);
        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("video/mp4");
        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/test.png");
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, file);
        Call<com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody> call = service.uploadVideo("desc", requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>(){ //error even before compile***
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (response.isSuccess())
                {
                    Log.i("mok","S");
                    ResponseBody rb = response.body();
                    Log.i("mok",rb.getUsername());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("mok","F");
                    com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody rb = response.errorBody();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) 
            {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("mok",t.getCause()+"");
                Log.i("mok","T");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**`UploadApiService`:**

```
public interface UploadApiService 
{
    @Multipart
    @POST("api/upload.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadVideo(@Part("description") String description, @Part("video") RequestBody video);
}
```

I guess I have to use a kind of `Stream` to keep track of the progress but unfortunately I don't know more.

Comment: For the compile error, posting the error would help track it down.  It looks good, so my random guess would be maybe your imports are wrong.  Make sure you import the correct `Callback`.  Should be `import retrofit.Callback;`, not `import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;`

Comment: @iagreen That was almost the answer. Indeed I found it before and wanted to delete this post, but if you post your answer I'll accept it. (I had another `ResponseBody` in another package created by myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you imports are the correct.  For example, `Callback` should be `retrofit.Callback;`, not `import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;`.  Based on your comment, it sounds like the real problem was a type conflict with a locally defined `ResponseBody`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Would you please take a look at this question that is a step after this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720583/response-issuccess-true-but-file-not-send